# Simplest process for switching displayed classes that extend JPanel in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, japplet, cardlayout

I have several classes which extend jpanel, many of which have parameters in their constructors.  Each already contains components, and they need to handle information and pass this information between each other.  I would like to display these panels on a website and to my understanding, the best solution is an applet.

I am also given to understand a cardlayout is probably what I need. I have no experience with cardlayout, and I need a way to switch between the panels based on a signal from inside the panels themselves.

For example, clicking the submit button on the login panel will bring up another panel which allows the user to select various options for the next panel to be displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: *"on a website and to my understanding, the best solution is an applet."*  If you change that to 'from a link on a web site' the best way to deploy the app, is to use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: That may work. However it has come to my attention that the school server I would be posting the site webpage to has a very intensive fire wall, which would prevent the applet/app from reaching the database. Now I need to find a way to have everything execute on the server side.  :( Unfortunately even if I get that working i am uncertain that the user input would make it through the fire wall.

Comment: Either both or neither of the applet or JWS app. will get through the firewall, in case there is any confusion on that matter.